# Nginx upstream servers all go down when one of them shuts down

Tags: node.js, nginx

I'm trying to set up upstream servers with nginx. All run the same Node.js app on port 8080 with pm2. Here is the nginx `default.conf` of the main server

```
upstream backend {
    ip_hash;
    server localhost:8080;
    server sv1_ip_address;
    server sv2_ip_address;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

And on `sv1` and `sv2`, I have the same `default.conf` as follows

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        ...
    }
}
```

Now when I tried shutting down either `sv1` or `sv2` (using `pm2 kill` for Node or even `reboot`), all upstream servers went down and I receive a 500 error (?) when accessing the app by the domain name. So I thought there was something wrong with nginx on those secondary servers and I replaced `upstream backend` with this

```
upstream backend {
    ip_hash;
    server localhost:8080;
    server sv1_ip_address:8080;
    server sv2_ip_address:8080;
}
```

and now shutting down or rebooting were handled correctly (meaning nginx will route the requests to one of the living servers). Is this an expected behavior, or am I doing something wrong here? I don't think routing requests directly to port 8080 is a good idea though.

Answer (score 0):

I donot know why you had to install `nginx` service on `sv1` and `sv2` servers.

When you reboot `sv1` , `sv2` servers, it should be enabling `nginx` first. Please check `service nginx status` is running or not once reboot is done.

And you `kill node` meaning application is down, so you got `500` error on `nginx`

Comment: Are you suggesting there's no need for nginx on the upstream servers? Please tell me why (I'm new).
Also, nginx is enabled. The app runs normally and automatically after rebooting. If the app running on 8080 is down, shouldn't nginx return 503 service unavailable instead of 500?

Comment: you mean you have installed `nginx` on `sv1` and `sv2` for health check, right ?

Comment: because its no need to go through 2 layers, `nginx` -- `nginx` -- `app` , just `nginx` --> `app`

Comment: You're right, I may not need the extra nginx layer. But it still doesn't answer why other servers stop working when 1 of them is down.

Comment: Actually, `ip_hash` will keep the session on each client machine, so if only one of their servers was down, on exact client got down status, it will be keeping that status all time. hope you understand my English :D

Comment: But shouldn't nginx redirect requests to the unavailable server to other servers in upstream? Isn't that how load balancing should work?

Comment: So I tried turning off either sv1 or sv2 (one at a time), which were being listened from port 80 of each IP in `upstream` and the problem persists. However, if I killed the Node process on the main server, which was being listened from `localhost:8080`, the other 2 still worked! So I think if I listen directly to the process' port, the error will be caught correctly with health check. But if I put them each behind a nginx, somehow the main nginx balancer failed to see the error.

Comment: remove this line `server sv1_ip_address;` on `upstream` on `nginx` proxy, and `reload nginx` , and shut down app on `sv1` and check again

Comment: The process on each server still works by itself. And the main balancer is still working with 2 servers left.

Comment: Well, I think I will go with connecting directly to port 8080 for now. Thank you for your help!